# Error when double-clicking TButton in FMX form application at design-time

Tags: firemonkey, design-time, delphi-xe8

In Delphi XE8 (Update 1), choose File > New > Multi-Device Application - Delphi > Blank Application.

Then put a `TButton` on the form.

Then double-click the button. This will automatically create the empty Click event-handler declaration and implementation (like with VCL form application projects):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```

However, it will also display an error message:

[image]

So why is this error message displayed? Is this a bug in the IDE? What can I do to prevent this error?

Comment: Submit a bug report on Quality Portal. In the meantime press OK and stop worrying about it.

Comment: Are sedative pills required as part of the development process?

Comment: OK, thanks for the hint. I've filed the bug report on Quality Portal.

Comment: Maybe try using actions and perhaps they behave better. Or perhaps select the event in the object inspector and double click there.

Comment: Even when double-clicking the event in the Object Inspector the error message is displayed.

Comment: Oh well, I tried my best!

Comment: And the error also occurs with actions.